# Reverse a string of numbers using a while loop (VB)

Tags: vb.net

I am fairly new to coding in VB and I am trying to reverse the string of numbers in the variable 'binary' by using a while loop (at the bottom of the code) but when the program runs I get a System.IndexOutOfRangeException error. What changes do I need to make to fix this?
Thanks

```
Module Module1


    Sub Main()
        Dim denary As Integer
        Dim binary As String = " "
        Dim x As Integer
        Dim y As Integer = 0
        Console.WriteLine("What is the denary number?") 'Asks the user what number denary number they want converted
        denary = Console.Read()

        While denary > 0 'Calculates the binary number, but reversed
            If denary Mod 2 = 0 Then
                binary = binary + "0"
                denary = denary / 2
            Else
                binary = binary + "1"
                denary = denary / 2
            End If
        End While

        Console.WriteLine("The binary equivalent is:" & binary) 'Prints the binary number in reverse
        Console.ReadLine()
        x = Len(binary)
        While x > 0
            Console.WriteLine(binary(x)) 'Print the correct binary equivalent (Not working)
            Console.ReadLine()
            x = x - 1
        End While


    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: This is a great problem to lean about debugging: breakpoints, watch variables etc.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array indexes start at 0, so the last one is always 1 less than the length of the array:

```
x = Len(binary) - 1
While x >= 0
  '...
```